# How to get Custom Swatch images on product list and view page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

i am not able to get assigned image from brand attribute,image showing image that is assigned to attribute value.

Comment: I want to get image that is assigned to particular attribute value.

Comment: hi are you there?

Comment: yes, I am here..

Comment: let me know custom swatch images mean?

Comment: it means i have to show country flag  with the brand name attribute. and in that i have created one field for uploading image while adding the values to the attribte.

Comment: so, have you created file attribute for  image? from product attribute?